# Unable to resolve mock[....] in playframework 2.6.17

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to mock ReactiveMongoAPI and for this i am writing the below code,

```
package controllers

import org.scalatest.mockito.MockitoSugar
import org.scalatestplus.play._
import org.scalatestplus.play.guice._
import play.api.test.Helpers._
import play.api.test._
import play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoApi


/**
 * Add your spec here.
 * You can mock out a whole application including requests, plugins etc.
 *
 * For more information, see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ScalaTestingWithScalaTest
 */
class HomeControllerSpec extends PlaySpec with GuiceOneAppPerTest with Injecting with MockitoSugar {

  val reactiveMongoApi: mock[ReactiveMongoApi]

  "HomeController GET" should {

    "render the index page from a new instance of controller" in {


      val controller = new HomeController(stubControllerComponents(), reactiveMongoApi)
      val home = controller.index().apply(FakeRequest(GET, "/"))
```

It gives me the error that it cannot resolve the mock[...].
Is there any way to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I bet you want to do as follows:

```
val reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi = mock[ReactiveMongoApi]
```